# copy an image obtained by ACTION_GET_CONTENT to external storage

Tags: android, android-storage

I would like to copy the image from the **ACTION_GET_CONTENT** and it should copy in Image directory in external storage.

I was getting the toast message but the image couldn't find in folder. Right now I giving permission manually so don't worry about that.

```
uriImagePath Gallary :content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A3934
Destination: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Seeker/Floor Plans"
```

I also added permission in the manifest file.

Here is my code. Any help much appreciated.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_PICTURE_FROM_GALLARY = 22;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    Button btn_copy;
    private String imagepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Seeker/Floor Plans/a.png";
    private Uri uriImagePath;
    private String realPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_copy = findViewById(R.id.btn_copy);

    }

    public void CopyImage(View view) {

        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        imagepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Seeker/Floor Plans";
        uriImagePath = Uri.fromFile(new File(imagepath));
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriImagePath);
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.name());
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_PICTURE_FROM_GALLARY);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Hi hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_PICTURE_FROM_GALLARY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();


            realPath = ImageFilePath.getPath(MainActivity.this, data.getData());
//                realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, data.getData());

            Log.d("onActivityResult", "Destination imagePath  :" + imagepath);
            Log.d("onActivityResult", "uriImagePath Gallary :" + data.getData().toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: file path : " + realPath);

            File f = new File(imagepath);
            if (!f.exists())
            {
                try {
                    f.createNewFile();
                    copyFile(new File(getRealPathFromURI(data.getData())), f);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Inside if creating new file and call copy function: ");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something Went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
        if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
            return;
        }

        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        if (destination != null && source != null) {
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        }
        if (source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if (destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {

        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Coul you start your post with supplying full path of source and destination?

Comment: @blackapps I added my source and destination path

Comment: 'pick path from the gallery' is not a full path. 'Internal Storage' is not the start of a full path.

Comment: @blackapps Can you check the updated source and destination

Comment: And please check my updated code as well

Comment: @blackapps I debug the code it not going in the if (!f.exists()) condition I am not sure why

Comment: `I would like to copy the image from the internal storage and it should copy in Image directory in internal storage.`No. You would like to copy an image obtained by ACTION_GET_CONTENT to external storage.

Comment: How about now ? @blackapps

Comment: A lot of code in CopyImag() does nothing and is only confusing. Change to: `public void CopyImage(View view) {

        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_PICTURE_FROM_GALLARY);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Hi hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }`

Comment: Actually that's onclick method when click on button open the gallery

Comment: `I was getting the toast message `. Which one?

Comment: It does not matter if it is in onClick. Please adapt your post.

Comment: Do away with getRealPathFromURI(Uri... And change the copy file function to `boolean copyFile(Uri uri, File file)`.

Comment: `Destination: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Seeker/Floor Plans"`. The asked full path would then be: /storage/emulated/0/Seeker/Floor Plans. Can you create that directory?

Comment: Directory its already there